# How to fix App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90784

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, bundle, plist

> App Store Connect Operation Error ERROR ITMS-90784: "Missing bundle
>   name. The Info.plist key CFBundleName is missing or has an empty value
>   in the bundle with bundle identifier 'com.xxxx.xxx'."

When try to upload my application to App Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**
Just set:

```
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```

in **info.plist** file in *Xcode*.